# Converting JCR Node to Vaadin Item (Magnolia)

Tags: vaadin, magnolia

Is there a class I can use to convert a JCR Node to a Vaadin Item?
Currently there's a way to get the JCR Node from the Vaadin Item by using the
 `Node relatedFieldItemNode = (JcrNodeAdapter)relatedFieldItem).getJcrItem()`

I was wondering if there's a way to do the reverse?

I'm trying this one in Magnolia.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, if you access to your data source say `Container`, then you may do

```
Container.getItem(Object itemId)
```

Hope that helps

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I can do the following to revert back to the Item again.

```
JcrNodeAdapter relatedFieldItemAdapter = new JcrNodeAdapter(relatedFieldItemNode)
```